# Has offscreen-tabs been removed from Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, offscreentabs

I'm looking at the `offscreen-tabs experimental API` [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/offscreen-tabs).

Then I tried to enable this but I don't see it in the chrome://flags/ part of the browser. Has it been removed from the browser as an experimental API or has it become a real API?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/offscreentabs/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes **Chrome OffScreen Tabs API was deleted** from chrome extensions code base on 13 Dec 2012 as shown in this [Patch / Changelist](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=172860&view=revision). This [Chrome Issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164408) asked to delete the specific API.

[Chrome Extension Dev Page for Offline Tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.offscreenTabs.html) also gives 404 that means corresponding document was also removed.

Answer (score -1):

try [this](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/) ref: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2765944#browsersettings

On your Windows computer, visit the Chrome Cleanup Tool website.
Click Download now.
Read the terms of service, and click Accept and Download.
When the file is downloaded, you'll see it at the bottom. Click the filename (chrome_cleanup_tool.exe).
Windows will ask if you want to run the file. Click Run.
The Chrome Cleanup Tool will scan your computer. You'll see a list of any malicious software found.
Click Remove suspicious programs.
Chrome will open a new tab, and ask you to reset your settings. Click Reset.